# bootstrap layout markup for right sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is what I want to achieve : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mClNE.png

How can I construct the above layout using bootstrap? The left part (2 col) and the right has 1 col, I color them so you can see.

The problem is this is not a static site. So here's the take for the markup

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        white
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        white
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        orange
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        white
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        white
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        orange
    </div>

</div>
```

the orange and the white will mix up in mobile and above markup is hard to maintain because I have to loop using php to display the content for the white box.

Comment: can you try adding float:left to your .col-lg-4 class and check

Comment: do you want it to be dynamic for any number of divs  or for just given divs ?

Comment: @RahulSambari the white box needed to be dynamic

Comment: You can put the white boxes in one column in a nested row and pull that left on the min width. I have provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do with the push and pull classes that come with bootstrap 3.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/riniri/1/

**This will have orange on top on small viewports (under the col-lg- class) and will be on the right when it's at that min-width or larger.**

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-8">
           <div class="box orange"></div>
           <div class="box orange"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8  col-lg-pull-4">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**DEMO CSS ONLY:**

```
.box {width:100%;height:300px;margin-bottom:30px;border:5px solid #000}
.orange {background:orange}
```

Comment: Hi Christina, if you inspect, the layout exceeded the width of the container which could cause problem in the future.

Comment: Bootstrap grid always exceeds the container width and then it's adjusted by negative margins and matching padding. Look at the docs for the grid system, this is accurate

Comment: also, it's using box-sizing border-box which includes padding and borders.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using many `rows`, Use one `row` which contains three children `divs`.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col1 col-lg-4" id="left">
       <div>White 1</div>
       <div>White 1</div>
       <div>White 1</div>
       <div>White 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col2 col-lg-4" id="middle">
       <div>White 2</div>
       <div>White 2</div>
       <div>White 2</div>
       <div>White 2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col3 col-lg-4" id="right">
       <div>Orange</div>
       <div>Orange</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The children `divs` (`White 1`, `White 2` and `Orange`) may be dynamically generated, and insert them correctly to the targets (`#left`, `#middle`, `#right`) by code (either PHP or JS).

Comment: great but it still have limitation, how can I let my orange stay on the top instead of bottom in mobile?

Comment: By HTML nature, top means first, while right means last. It is not intuitive to implement such a result with plain css. You need to use Media Query solution: place the orange to the first place so it will on top (on small screen) by default; when large screen size is detected, add/apply a float:right css on it so it will be on the right.

Comment: media query with javascript?

Comment: Not necessary, this layout pattern works with the push and pull classes and a nested row.